# Is there a way to make pagination on 4th segment in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, segment

So, here is my url: http://example.com/ci/index.php/home/sort_by_week
As you see, my 3rd segment is ***sort_by_week***, but i need to make pagination on this page, is there a way to get the 4th segment? I already tried to do ***$this->uri->segment(4)*** in pagination script, it didn't work. Can someone help me and give an extended explanation on how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes bro you can handle it very easily**

```
$this->load->library('pagination');

$config['base_url'] = 'http://example.com/ci/index.php/home/sort_by_week';
$config['total_rows'] = 100;
$config['per_page'] = 10;
$config['uri_segment'] = 4; 

$this->pagination->initialize($config); 

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
```

You must have to put this **$config['uri_segment'] = 4;** so codeigniter can setup your pagination on 4th segment.

For More Information: [Codeigniter Pagination Library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html)

Comment: Welcom bro :) take care